# AngularJs console.log "$q is not defined"

Tags: angularjs, breeze, promise, angular-promise

I am getting this error in the console `$q is not defined`. When I did some research I found some thing like `.q library has been deprecated` from 
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs

If this is so, then the whole concept of promises is also deprecated,

Comment: Have you injected $q into the scope you're working in?

Comment: Please consider updating us on progress and giving me feedback on the answer :)

Answer (score 25):

Promises are not deprecated. In fact they're gaining quite a lot of momentum lately and are included in the next version of JavaScript.

Let's look at what they say:

> This breeze.angular.q library has been deprecated. It is superseded by the Breeze Angular Service which more cleanly configures breeze for Angular development.
>
> The Breeze Angular Service tells Breeze to use Angular's `$q` for promises and to use Angular's `$http` for ajax calls.

What they say is that breeze uses Angular's own promises for promises rather than its own `breeze.angular.q` which uses Q promises which are more able but also much heavier than `$q` promises which Angular uses. This is simply an API change.

Inside Angular code, you can obtain `$q` using dependency injection - for example with the simple syntax:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($q){
    //$q is available here
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to use it independently you can use service location and obtain `$q` directly from an injector, but that's rarely the case. (If you want an example - let me know, I'd just rather not include code that's usually indicative of bad practice).

Comment: Hey, thanks, at first i would like to agree that i am not that familiar about angular concepts, So while searching through the promises documents, i found http://www.techjini.com/blog/javascript-promises/, Is this documentation is correct, If not correct me . Thanks a lot Brother

Comment: @RaviMone if you create a short example on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.com) or another such website I can take a look and try to understand what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 9):

```
# in your console, try following code
$injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
q = $injector.get('$q');
deferred = q.defer();
# then do whatever you want
```