# $q is undefined - Reference error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have the following angular code:

```css
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name .cordova
 * @description
 * # cordova
 * Factory in the APP.
 */
angular.module('app')
  .factory('cordova', function () {
    // Service logic
    // ...
    
    var d = $q.defer(),  
    resolved = false;

    var self = this;  
    this.ready = d.promise;

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            resolved = true;
            d.resolve($window.cordova);
        });

    // Check to make sure we didn't miss the
    // event (just in case)
    setTimeout(function () {  
        if (!resolved) {
            if ($window.cordova) d.resolve($window.cordova);
        }
    }, 3000);

    // Public API here
    return this;  

    /*var meaningOfLife = 42;

    // Public API here
    return {
      someMethod: function () {
        return meaningOfLife;
      }
    };*/
});
```

But I get the following error:

```css
ReferenceError: $q is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/cordova.js:15:13)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4625:19)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4464:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4625:19)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4424:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4571:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4595:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4637:18)
    at $controller (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10042:28)
    at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:1007:26) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

And here is my index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">

    

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/cordova.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.factory('cordova', function ($q) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs console.log "$q is not defined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379733/angularjs-console-log-q-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to inject `$q` in yout factory

```
angular.module('app').factory('cordova', function ($q) {
    // Some code...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Any idea on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646564/unable-to-invoke-controller-constructor-and-submit-function?noredirect=1#comment60888551_36646564

Comment: Check out my answer to see if it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Cool ;) Thanks a ton!